# Why cant i see my hotbar and or any buttons even though i have hide hud off?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play on mobile android and a few days ago I was playing and my controls, hotbar and even the other players went invisible. I already tried turning off my hide HUD and that didn't help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: Oops sorry minecraft

Comment: Ill add the tag, but watch out! I flagged your question for clarity, sorry...

Comment: Oh ok.... I don't know what you mean though this is my first ever comment here

Comment: If that's the case, Welcome to arqade! Remember to read the Tour to get a good bit of knowledge about the site.

Comment: Oh ok thankyou do you happen t know the solution to my problem?

Comment: Not really. I play Java more than Bedrock.

Comment: Check that your button size isn't like 5 or something and if you have any resource packs disable them and see if that fixes it.